# Why does my title tag not appear on search results using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a title tag to my website using ROR.

After adding the desired changes to  ...  in aplication.html.erb, then commiting and deploying it, I still do not see the complete title tag present with the changes I just made when I view the website on search results.

Why is this the case and is there anything I am forgetting to include?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Website Name - Desired title tag added here but doesn't show in search results</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="body-interior">
      <%= render 'shared/header' %>
      <div class="container">
       <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
          <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
        <% end %>

       <%= yield %>
      </div>

    <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
  </div>
    <%= render 'shared/final_scripts' %>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart the server after deploying the code changes?

Comment: What search results? Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say search results, I assume you mean search engines like Google? If so, you need to know that changes like these won't be recognized instantly by Google. The changes should be visible as soon as Google (or any other robot) crawls the page in question again.

As far as I know you can force this process with Google's Webmaster Tools.